# Does Forms.SetAuthenticationCookie put a cookie on the server or client?

Tags: forms-authentication

I have a server located at `www.abc.com` that makes a call to a web app on `www.def.com` and if the user coming from `www.abc.com`, authenticates on `www.def.com`, I call `Forms.SetAuthenticationCookie`.

Does the cookie get placed on the `client (www.abc.com)` or the `server (www.def.com)`?  If it stores it on the server, how could I store it on the client instead?

Answer (score 0):

Forms authentication cookie is nothing but the container for forms authentication ticket. The ticket is passed as the value of the forms authentication cookie with each request and is used by forms authentication, on the server, to identify an authenticated user.

However, if we choose to use cookieless forms authentication, the ticket will be passed in the URL in an encrypted format. Cookieless forms authentication is used because sometimes the client browsers block cookies.

Hope it hepls.

Comment: Right now, I have been testing with two different web apps on my localhost, one acting like the client and acting like the server and it works.  I haven't been able to determine if it will work cross-domain yet, but was wondering if I will run into problems if that does happen?

Comment: I think it's possible to share it by url(contain ticket) cross domain but haven't test it. One thing you should do is to add same validationKey and decryptionKey attributes in the machineKey element in each site. The validationKey and decryptionKey values must be identical on all web server.